# How to return two dictionaries in views.py

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

How to return infos and data in views.py?

I tried:

return render(request, 'index.html', {'infos':infos}, data)

return render(request, 'index.html', {'infos':infos, 'data':data})

but nothing works

---

views.py

```
def contact(request):

   infos = Info.objects.all()
   if request.method == "POST":
       form = ContactForm(request.POST)
       if form.is_valid():
           messages.success(request, 'Success')
           admin_address = "mail"
           responder_address ="responder@site.pl"
           client_address = request.POST['email']
           message_for_admin = """
           name: %s;
           E-mail: %s;
           Subject: %s;
           Text: 
           %s;

           """ % (request.POST['name'], request.POST['email'], request.POST['subject'],    request.POST['message'])

           message_for_client = """
           text
           """

           try:
               send_mail(request.POST['subject'], message_for_admin, responder_address, [admin_address,])
               #send_mail(request.POST['subject'], responder_address, message_for_client, [client_address,])
           except BadHeaderError:
               print('wrong subject')
           data['form'] = form
           data['info'] = 'thanks for message'
       else:
           data['form'] = ContactForm()

   return render(request, 'index.html', {'infos':infos})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `render` shortcut takes a single context dictionary. You can't pass it two dictionaries.

For your example, you can add `infos` to the data dictionary:

```
data['infos'] = infos
```

Then render the template with `data`

```
return render(request, 'index.html', data)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
# you might have forgot to write else part for GET method

def contact(request):
   data = {}
   infos = Info.objects.all()
   form = ContactForm()
   if request.method == "POST":
       ....
       ....

   return render(request, 'index.html', {'infos':infos, 'data':data})
```

Comment: If you do this, then you can't access items from `data` directly in the template. For example, you would do `{{ data.form }}` instead of `{{ form }}`.